# What does the "Show All Input Sources" option do?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, input-language, gnome-tweak-tool, input-method

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and upon launching the `gnome-tweak-tool` and going to the `Keyboard and Mouse` I find that there is an option called `Show All Input Sources` which is currently set to `OFF` I assume that this relates to the `Input Sources` list in the `Region & Language` settings? If so, when enabling this option, what exactly will it show differently? Which input sources will it should that it does not already? And why are these other input sources hidden by default anyway?

[image: Show All Input Sources Option]

Comment: I think some additional input sources, which the developers didn't think should be shown by default, will be added to the list. You'd better ask the GNOME developers about the reason. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are related to ibus ([Intelligent Input Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus)).

Run `ibus-setup` and you will be prompted with a gui and the middle tab will show the installed "input methods". You can add and view input methods here. I would assume that the "Show All Input Sources" will show all of the installed input methods (btw: "input methods" is the same (but old name it seems) for "input sources").

[image]

'add' will show the languages

[image]

`kbd` is an input source that provides keyboard layouts as input method methods especially for European keyboards. There are [several others](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Input_method_engines), like [anthy](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=ibus-anthy) for japanese, [pinyin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Pinyin_usage) or [chewing](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=ibus-chewing) for chinese.